# Parallel/ Concurrent Approval

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, internal-transactions

I am trying to develop a document verification app that needs multiple levels of approval...

How do I implement a parallel/ concurrent approval mechanism in Blockchain?

I need it like the nodes have permission to approve or reject a transaction, but I can't find any commands for that in geth.